# Pull request review from user without access to repo

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

I've been getting frequent emails saying something like...

> *Hello, please review and approve [this PR (link)](https://github.com/corporate-org/my-private-repo/pull/2)*

...only to be served a 404 from [octobiwan](https://octodex.github.com/octobiwan). Inevitably I'll reply...

> I don't seem to have access to this repo, can you make sure you've sent me the correct link and that you've granted me appropriate permissions?

...and hear back...

> *How do I grant you permissions?*

I would *like* to say in general...

> Please don't email me anymore. You can request a review from me by [selecting my name from the drop-down](https://help.github.com/en/articles/requesting-a-pull-request-review). If you don't see my name, then I can't review it and you need to [get an admin to grant me access](https://help.github.com/en/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization) to do so first.

Intuitively I *expect* that you can only request a review from someone who has access to complete the review; and a few spot checks *appear* to confirm this behavior. However, since I can't find anything explicitly confirming this, I wanted to ask the internet:

#### Can you request a GitHub code review from a user without access to complete it?

...and is there official wording somewhere that this is or is not the case? Is the following row from the [org permissions matrix](https://help.github.com/en/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization) as explicit as it gets?

```
+------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Repository action      |     Read    |    Write    |    Admin    |    Owner    |
|                        | permissions | permissions | permissions | permissions |
+------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| …                                                                              
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Submit reviews on pull |      X      |      X      |      X      |      X      |
| requests               |             |             |             |             |
+------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following documentation states that you can only request a PR if someone has read-only access. This would imply they should stop sending you emails directly and use the feature that automatically sends an email request once they are assigned.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/requesting-a-pull-request-review

> Repository owners and collaborators can request a pull request review from anyone with read access to the repository. Organization members can also request a pull request review from teams with read access to the repository. The requested reviewer or team will receive a notification that you asked them to review the pull request.